# How should I name a plain class (and its file) in Angular?

Tags: angular

What's the convention to name a simple class (and its file) in Angular?

Let's say I have to create a class call Utility. Of course I can't name it **UtilityComponent (utility.component.ts)** or **UtilityService (utility.service.ts)**, ecc.

Is it correct to name the class just **Utility** and the file **utility.ts**?

Thank you

Comment: Yes its choice up to you. you can use it like `UtilityModel` or `UtilityData`.

Comment: @er-sho thank you man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes thats a good naming. You can make an extra folder, name it e.g. "Utilities", then put the file utility.ts in there.